# Парапет с колоннами

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно называть этот архитектурный объект? Парапет с колоннами? Колонный парапет? Парапетная колоннада? Парапет в колониальном стиле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала разберемся в терминологии. 
Парапет - (от франц. parapet, итал. parapetto, от parare - защищать и petto - грудь) - ограда, перила или невысокая сплошная стенка, проходящая по краю крыши, террасы, балкона, вдоль моста, набережной (в качестве заграждения) на гребне плотины, мола, дамбы (для защиты от разрушений волнами) . 
Обычно он бывает разных видов.
Архитектурное сооружение, которое Вы приводите в ссылке, называется балюстрада. Корректно: ***Парапет в форме балюстрады; балюстрадный парапет.*** См.:[Словарь](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=614.0veFF4D4BmjTRFPDsA9USSt1LZ6lTsUBpGOSjp0OwRCAeBQn1Ye9EO1CjprghRd8hvTIdRqICr1uYSmlsZ-hCg.67b40a9ab5b97cd846327e198865e3576ac30a39&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xti-b8lArfpY2fz6fP4kJz3WO16v4q1mdjGbU2_f8A61RSPoVqF8dZTBHgEV6oZ8Y0CvJCjF2bOwvTvIigrwrKLTzUazkEIXmRrSnq6936LI4qMbnLrbSh6Qrhrc3SI9bYkrKX9hpQnMv4btRYIDkLmJ0HvAmWVx1UyVwmBT_NN1vKaomcImPF9g6pumrciEmwnM9ATLgSS8VcNeSi9lk--gOwaSI_q1sY&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxc1BvYnJ3UU14Yk14cFE2Rm9xbmxxRU9MQ0hwR2d4SkZMTXdEZHg5Y3ZULTJLMEhnenlDVlQ5c0pQNER6SXJUeGNTMmRJenpuRjBRLWNVdWM2UnA1NHIxRnpoa0tTb0JRU0I0UndMeU5MU1NJcFZJdzVnRG5WVm1wMGpwZWdJSHRTVFlkRWxsdldHcVJtRG5taW1iN0d2d1FFWjdLRHpPWURMYTdGemplS3ZyTFZlOFRkaEQwWUVYQW5KN2JEY0FOSV9qNTdWb0F0Q192TEhPZzFLYXJsTGFZSUlscjVOX0RfRU1FYnNqSFptbzFVZzNiWE10eDFzZUNEb01JTEhGQXI3R0dpUzdyMzljSnZzZ2xxcVg3ZFNwaUx2TWhYbk0yZTJ2OWZJMzZYN2otSWlCTVNHVWN3cmliaTAxdXFMYXhsVlY2VUpkMUhfYzNZaW9oZDBULXQ2SVJLQUV4YkNMMjQ2cFFMTmxGa0ll&b64e=2&sign=2b55aa0e9a3d89177c3c9a8bf330fc88&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3m4cVndcRMfNuguIXI6uHFKopKeimbzjng6f6vrmcjv6Th2-5XYdI2qmPMFfvyziMF_apt2QDNHP5o59pu397B4Bu-vzksTe8LPNeWSgtU1rKhcHe2iN7jy92VfxpRpGfObN9WD8SHGXth0rf5X7Hxzo1d2ZeRjZFLStw6ne_d5-ZexI7mXqVIz9yRhb49P7xIed1-xpzpQFSt6Pi631NG4zwxLmbVlveJ-m8cxWO-nwZTL8OZIxUIqDO8lCVfrKnN6CD0Y5nfvCdt7yEXHlhN8d0g3ITSj5IVkeJ0twT3VzDOxdp0EEwG7PrcsyopKRJT4aGxxG0rAMzzXIqc_ByluSDkPeLVc4An6wSsKu0MThggRkPsmpqDAZ65m6sGMXlVuNxxOuja_DY1xfNqKWiioP-AlKOfRnQFswZxwH7yLwp6FjE1fcaUwJViqdPRdCFvT8FVwtavesAHodo6RIjQDFvOtd8rWaFmWYGjlJmKumvbS3jpkNURGdt5N44QwPcMCjSQD3D3rjjMbzPYU0SJziGf0Alqm2MFfQcnXW9wY6BtPce2c0NcBJmQ54_wP36wf22cOS377MSz_DXeVVt-ZfrdRYibEyfw2Uc_RE_zDcPlx5mQL_PKsAb0_k5Jzb70yp6ceilfBPBHicKrJkas39IOdgdutOuK_ErniZg2noIIBEzNcVcyOfnRb8BVCHZZ4-fya3amYtv3gxycLBGWkedaSjXxASygV9o6lFm42rdb-0iLeUlhtyIaylb07tQDbaJq2m5cESehHdxiaIcTzvItudpdXzKVRQdk7Ir_6PBYNV7FPCPsqz3ZKTpUaS4BHXxOk3T7_1IJ3aOjJ2xpQaHysKpyMSrUmqmc7h_rTPhlY7opgxgKvhm4R9Lz76xrlomH5_QmB6DKDiQbOUaQ1biBEGUuxRYgoPl7VF2PODGKW9Bvc2SOL_xHBcORyLDYrhbg420xDMhRAvFAde-TK96tT6yEtH8ZXNtOqQW8lIVv3MVdH2L50_fSuFmCHuRebSYc-YJn9qDG7I1jZ_mmqL51CzxsA8cXRbRtNWC9sgBKb4EzDVcwDyq_pdYWxhe9TW0-4lZ2LnDHiBPECcjbGlLsWyfx8xhqAb8TBz9P_NNbOBEq1xfY3oC2ZItV_D75z8f3E_1pT1AmnixsOWqSZ4gx7dO608V3D5tcNNBe_nMt0CTsyV_rDQ&l10n=ru&cts=1425195308463&mc=4.472981213908804)

Answer (score 1):

Если имеется в виду объект, по сторонам которого (с равным шагом) стоят (однотипные) колонны, то такое здание или сооружение именуется периптером от греч. peripteros.

Comment: @shampar, нет имеется ввиду нечто вроде этого http://ckdoma.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/0_72c3c_b9fb273b_XL.jpeg

Comment: Третий глаз! Вас трудно было понять, т.к. архитектурным объектом балюстраду называть не следует, - только элементом; балясину выдавать за колонну тоже неправильно. Дадим этому вопросу статус розыгрыша?

Comment: @shampar, Балюстраду вполне возможно назвать архитектурном объектом(сооружением). См.: [Сооружение](http://dic.academic.ru/contents.nsf/ruwiki/)

Comment: Серж! Не смешите людей!